# How to Retrieve Post by Each Category in a Blog and Place them on postlist html page in django

Tags: python, html, django

Am creating a blog and a news website in django which have a specific category displayed on its hompage.
That is the specific category for news,  Politics and education are beeing displayed on my post_list.html.
I get a no exception provided when i try to retrieve it by

> Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=["news"])

This is the model for my category

```
class Category(models.Model): 
         name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
         slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

This is the model for my Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*This is the view for my postlist

```
class PostListView(ListView):
       model = Post 
       template_name = blog/post_list.html
       context_object_name = "posts"
       ordering = ["date_posted"
       paginate_by = 5


def get_queryset(self):
    posts = 
    get_object_or_404(Post)
    return  Post.objects.filter().order_by( "-date_posted")


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter()[0:4] 
    context['new_cat'] =Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=[" news"])[0.5] 
    context['new_politics'] = Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=["politics"])[0.5]
 
    return context ***
```

> This is my pos_tlist.html code for retrieving post by category in news

```
  <div> <h1>News</h1> <div/>  
{% for post in new_cat%} 
  div class="mt-2" 
 <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img class="object-cover w-full rounded-lg" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }} cover"> </a></div>
<div class="py-2 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><h1 class="hover:text-blue-600 text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2 py-2">{{ post.title }}</h1></a></div> '''
```

> I get a no exception provided for this post when i run python manage.py runserver
> But when i go to my shell ,  python manage.py shell
> I get a full list of all the post.
> But it refuses to display on hompage
> I need help in doing this and making all my category appear per category on news page
> Is there any solution for all my post to appear category by category on post_list.html and homepage

In summary- i can't filter post that have a Foreign key Models like Category,  Author  in my Post Model.
I can directly filter post from the post model but i can't filter post title from the category Name models

That means when i try to filter  Post.objects.all() then all my post will come out but when i try Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=["news"]) nothing will show in my page except no exeption error

Help

Comment: So, `Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=["news"])` returns no posts, means you don't have any posts with such category name?

Comment: I have alot of post associated with the news category on my database but it still returns no exception provided yet for post but it returns list of post on ahell but not on post list,  but did you see anything wrong with my code

Comment: Please clean up the code in your question so it is exactly as you have it, I see some weird things like `return context ***`, `ordering = ["date_posted"` without closing bracket, `posts = get_object_or_404(Post)`, `[0.5]` as array index

Answer (score 2):

Could a problem be in whitespace you have in " news" here?

```
Post.objects.filter(category__name__in=[" news"])[0.5]
```

Also, what is `[0.5]`? I guess you want `[0:5]` there?

Also, make sure your `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` methods are indented properly. Because if they have no indent as you showed it then they defined outside of your `PostListView` class...

Comment: This answer here really solved my problem ,  thanks so much man ,  it was indeed the white space error or an oversight error

I mistakenly did [0.5] instead of [0:5]

Oversight error sir
Thanks for ur help